# Toggle MVC user login method: Forms + AD Account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, forms-authentication

What if I am creating an intranet web application using MVC and in the administration's access panel I need to provide a way for users to login either via AD accounts or simple windows forms login-password combination.

The only way **I see** to accomplish that is to somehow switch on-the-fly the web-config file, allowing or disallowing the anonymous login and hence either or not to check inferred windows account name.

Two questions actually here: is there any **more right way** of doint it, and if not, what is the best way to change web.config file on-the-fly and is it really appropriate for accomplishing my goal?

Comment: Why not query AD directly via LDAP..  in your authentication logic, have a switch that either queries AD or the database based on the type of user.. at the top of each request: wash, rinse, repeat.. yes, there are -much- more complicated SSO-esque solutions, but int this case the out of the box controls might not do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way I see to accomplish that is to somehow switch on-the-fly the web-config file

Oh no, you are really very far from the truth.

Your scenario is actually very common. You could externalize the authentication to a separate service using [`WIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) (Windows Identity Foundation). Here are some [`introductory slides`](http://www.slideshare.net/manz1234/wif). The idea is to federate authentication through a single sign on provider. And here's a [`similar question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958364/username-and-password-authentication-for-wif-windows-identity-foundation-in-as) to yours.